# How does Matlab determine size of BytesAvailable for Serial Connection?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

How does Matlab determine the value of the BytesAvailable which is used in the tmtool for serial connection?

I have to send, say 512 bytes from my Matlab to my device over UART. The problem is only 96 bytes are sent to my device. i don't understand what happened to my remaining bytes! FYI: The value of BytesAvailableFcnCount being shown now is 48. On checking [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailablefcncount.html/), I found that the default value is 48. So I increased it to 512; but the same issue recurred. I have BytesAvailable being shown still 95!

Please suggest me some way. I have pasted the code in which I am trying to do this:

```
fopen(obj1);  //obj1 is the name of my serial object
A = fopen('Path of the file I am using');
txdata = fread(A,[5 100],'uint8','ieee-be');
[my_count_rows, my_count_columns]=size(txdata);
for my_i = 1:my_count_columns
    for jjj = 1:my_count_rows
        fwrite(obj1,txdata(jjj,my_i),'uint8');
    end
end
```

Comment: The `BytesAvailableFcnCount` is relevant when receiving bytes, it indicates at which number of a receiving serial port triggers the callback function. Are you using the `BytesAvailableFcn` at all? If `BytesAvailable` is 95, it seems your device returns some kind of ack. Read these acks from your serial port before sending the next bytes, probably the input buffer of your device is full because you are sending to fast.

Comment: @Daniel:No, I am only sending from Matlab to my device. But I am pretty sure, my device is not sending any ACKs because these 95 bytes I see in my device's memory(my intended target). How do you propose to slow down the sending speed? my input buffer size is 512